# Capturing sound by ALSA

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, alsa, libalsa

I am trying to capture the sound from sound card by ALSA in linux systems. Its read the data from the vector in PCM format. I need a way to find out the right way to capturing and save it to in the file and play to check the recevied data is correct or not.

Comment: Did you study the source code of free software similar to your goals (probably some mixer software)?

Comment: Its reading the data by interleaved method[left and rigth consecutively].

Comment: i need a way to parse  that data and save

Comment: https://gist.github.com/albanpeignier/104902
I am using the code from the above the link for capturing the audio data from the vector and store bytes in the file i want to play that file and check  data parsing correct or not. using the "Audacity" for rading as  raw data but i am not hearing any valuable audio.

Answer (score 2):

To capture audio to a file with alsa , you can use [arecord](http://linux.die.net/man/1/arecord). By using this you can simply capture input audio to a file. Or you can write your own application which read PCM data. You can use [snd_pcm_readi](http://alsa-lib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.15/group__PCM_ga4c2c7bd26cf221268d59dc3bbeb9c048.html) API for this purpose.

Comment: Yes i have used this API and reading data in the buffer . i want to save the buffer as audio file and want to play. when i tried its played as mute  state not hearing any sound from the file.

Comment: i need a way to save the file in the right format and play.

Comment: immanuel, writing to file is not important... u can use normal file write for that purpose. But playing is important.. How u played PCM data?. Also make sure that input data is not mute..

Comment: I wrote a file and opened in the default format. Its opened in the adobe photo shop and its opened as stereo and set the other thing when its start to play its playing but getting any sound .

Comment: How can we play pcm data?

Comment: did you heard  about [aplay](http://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay)? u can use this command for play PCM. You can use the software **audacity** also for playing pcm.